# Are there "Space Jellyfish" in Florida? Would they be possible?

Tags: launch, nasa, atmosphere, identify-this-object

The Wikipedia article [Space Jellyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_jellyfish) shows the image below with the caption:

> A California space jellyfish from 22 December 2017

I think that when other Q&A here have shown similar space jellyfishes, they've also been from California launches.

Have space jellyfishes been reported and photographed associated with launches from Florida as well? Would they be possible? Enquiring minds want to know!

[image: "Space Jellyfish"] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Plume_from_SpaceX_Launch_of_Iridium-4_Falcon_9_Flight_46.jpg)

---

Related phenomenon:

- [Why is one of these two concurrent fuel-dump spirals blue?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24414/12102)
- [Why did the "Secretive SpaceX Zuma Launch" make a big "S" or yin-yang shape in the sky?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24408/12102)
- in Astronomy SE: [Was the recent blue spiral over Hawaii really a SpaceX rocket dumping fuel?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/52006/7982)

Comment: [Rule for deciding the plural form of “space jellyfish”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/492223/217285)

Comment: I think any launch at dawn or dusk could do this, but the time window is extended if the launch is toward the hidden sun (staying out of shadow).  CA is mostly for polar (or retrograde) orbits, and FL for prograde, so CA would have longer time window at dusk, and FL at dawn.  More eyes are open at dusk.

Comment: @amI you could probably post that as a partial answer, I've made a small adjustment to the title.

Comment: I'm no authority, but I now see that wikipedia shows jellyfishes in FL (and Russia) -- so obviously possible.

Comment: @amI my offer still holds!